# read previous parent state in componentDidUpdate of child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

having a component declared like this:

```
<MyComp value={this.state.form1.val1} />
```

inside MyComp componentDidUpdate I would like to know what was the previous value of `state.form1.val1`
(by previous value I mean the value of `val1` property of the previous state object)

```
export default class MyComp extends React.Component {
...
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
       // compare current value of val1 with previous value of val1
       // prevState is null here becuase MyComp has no state, its parent has state
      }
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh the OP is using `componentDidUpdate` (not deprecate) and `componentDidMount` will not be deprecated anytime soon. `getDerivedStateFromProps` has a different purpose and its use is discouraged by facebook itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 alternatives:

- take advantage in `componentDidUpdate` in **parent component**.
- pass it by props and catch it in `componentDidUpdate` in **child component**

**Parent component**

```
<MyChildComponent myProp={this.state.myValue} />
```

**Child component**

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      console.log(prevProps.myProp)
    }
```

Notice that React's components trigger `componentDidUpdate` when its state changes or new props are received.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more, how do I pass the current and subsequent states by props, so I could compare them after

Comment: weirdly componentDidUpdate wasn't being called on each setState (called onChange for a editor compoenent), only on my form reset button, but now after I restarted VSCode and "npm start" it does work

Answer (score 1):

The previous value of `state.form1.val1` of the parent component will be `prevProps.value` inside `componentDidUpdate` of `MyComp`. The current value will be `this.props.value` inside `componentDidUpdate`.

You can not access the state of the parent component directly from within a child component, only the stuff which is explicitly passed down.

Comment: the `prevProps.value` in my case is the value of the initial state (when the page loaded). On each change of MyComp value I call setState and componentDidUpdate doesn't fire in those cases, only when I click the reset button and I reset the state, in at that point prevProps.value will be the value that was set initially not the previous one